# flutter putting data from api in expansion tile

Tags: flutter

Hew guys , i got a small question .

im making a drawer that should have a titles and a neste titles so i use an expansion tile.

so the titles are displayed but when i press the arrow to open the nested titles it gives me an error.

i used future builder in the nested titles i think this is the problem the error gives me this

```
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<dynamic>>#aeb31):
Unexpected null value.
```

this is my drawer

[Drawer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwUwI.png)

this is my drawer code

```
import 'package:MyCima/Screens/drawer_title_page.dart';
import 'package:MyCima/models/drawer_shows_data_model.dart';
import 'package:MyCima/services/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class FilmsDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilmsDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FilmsDrawerState createState() => _FilmsDrawerState();
}

class _FilmsDrawerState extends State<FilmsDrawer> {
  final ServicesClass _services = ServicesClass();
  late DrawerShowsDataModel _showsModelClass;
  late Future drawerListData;
  List nestedListNames = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    drawerListData = getDrawerList();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List> getDrawerList() async {
    return await _services.getFilms('menus');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      elevation: 150,
      semanticLabel: 'More Shows',
      backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: drawerListData,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 9,
                            child: Text(
                              'MyCima',
                              style: GoogleFonts.bevan(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Divider(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              indent: 64,
                              endIndent: 64,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 95,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            _showsModelClass = DrawerShowsDataModel.fromJson(
                                snapshot.data[index]);
                            if (_showsModelClass.listChildren.length > 0) {
                              return ExpansionTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  _showsModelClass.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                children: [
                                  getNestedTitles(index),
                                ],
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                child: TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                const DrawerTitlePage()));
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${_showsModelClass.name}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return const Center(child: Text('No Connection'));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getNestedTitles(int index){

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getDrawerList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data![index]['children'].length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            _showsModelClass = DrawerShowsDataModel.fromNestedJson(snapshot.data![index]['children'][index]);
            return TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                '${_showsModelClass.name}',
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer

we need to make a list of widgets and add widgets on it then use it in the expansion

```
List<Widget> list = [];
```

```
List<Widget> getNestedTitles(int index) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    drawerListData.then((value) {
      for (var x in value[index]['children']) {
        list.add(Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                      const DrawerTitlePage()));
            },
            child: Text('${x['name']}',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),),
          ),
        ));
      }
    });
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to so similar things, but when my data amount is larger, then it seems to take a longer time to build the UI. Is there any way to help improve performance for this?